# Scrollbar arrows do not get redrawn while thumbtrack gets redrawn correctly

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a custom control by registering a new class for it and instantiating it as a child to a top-level window. The control is basically a list. In order to save some effort, I decided to use the WS_VSCROLL window class in order to add scrollbars to my custom control.

My trouble is that when I resize the window, I proceed to recalculate the size of the thumbtrack and page size, etc. then call SetScrollInfo with the redraw variable set to true. This redraws the thumbtrack correctly, but the arrows do not get redrawn. Therefore, if I resize the window from below, [the top arrow is still good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US5dw.png), but the bottom one goes missing. If I resize to the right, then both arrows change position [and so both disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVmm5.png).

I can't seem to find a way to get a handle to the internal scrollbar control that WS_VSCROLL creates in order to call an invalidate on it or something. I really don't know how to proceed form here. One thing to keep in mind is that if I add CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW to the top level window, everything gets drawn correctly, so I know that at least the internal values are all fine. It's just that that way I get too much redrawing and flicker.

EDIT: I'm posting some code. I really wanted to avoid this because I'll probably be put to shame, but please know that probably no one but myself will ever use it.

The control is a column of tweets similar to how Tweetdeck works. Each tweet is also a custom control, but that paints just fine and I have no problems there. The column control itself does not respond to WM_PAINT at all because it just contains Tweet controls, which handle their own painting.

Here are also the window classes for each of these:

- register class of top level is NULL and CreateWindow class is WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CLIPCHILDREN.
- register class of column is NULL and CreateWindow class is WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL.
- register class of tweet is NULL and CreateWindow class is WS_CHILD.

Code:

```
LRESULT Column::OnResize(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) // responds to WM_SIZE
{
    // global height var
    lastWidth = width;
    lastHeight = height;
    width = LOWORD(lParam);
    height = HIWORD(lParam);
    //updateScrollPageSize();

    SCROLLINFO si;
    si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
    si.fMask  = SIF_ALL;
    GetScrollInfo (hWnd, SB_VERT, &si);

    // Resize all child tweets
    if (lastWidth != width ||
        lastHeight != height && si.nMax - si.nPos < height)
    {
        // C++0x lambdas can only take in local variables?!
        int localWidth = width;
        int *tweetBottomPtr = &lastTweetBottom;
        *tweetBottomPtr = 0;
        std::for_each(tweets.begin(), tweets.end(),
                      [localWidth, tweetBottomPtr, &si](TweetBox *tweet)
        {
            MoveWindow(tweet->getHandle(),
                       tweet->getX(), *tweetBottomPtr - si.nPos,
                       localWidth, tweet->getHeight(), TRUE);
            *tweetBottomPtr += tweet->getHeight();
        });
    }

    updateScrollPageSize();
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
void Column::updateScrollPageSize()
{
    SCROLLINFO si;
    // Set the vertical scrolling range and page size
    si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
    si.fMask  = SIF_ALL;
    GetScrollInfo (hWnd, SB_VERT, &si);

    si.fMask  = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE;
    si.nMin = 0;
    si.nMax = lastTweetBottom;
    si.nPage  = (int)((float)height / lastTweetBottom * si.nMax);
    SetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Is your scroll bar implemented on the child window or the parent window?

Comment: On the child window, my custom class.

Comment: Are what are you using to draw your class with, D2D , GDI, GDI+ , DirectX what?

Comment: I'm using GDI to draw a tiny bit and my control makes use of other standard controls as children such as a rich edit box.

Comment: Something odd is going on here... the scrollbars are what's called "non-client area" controls - they share the same handle with the main window (which is why there's no internal handle for them), and Windows should take care of drawing them. It's somewhat similar to how Windows manages the titlebar or menu on top-level windows. CS_H/VREDRAW shouldn't make a difference here, they decide whether the entire client area should be invalidated when size changes, but shouldn't affect how the nonclient area paints. Can you post your code that creates, sizes and draws the windows?

Comment: @BrendanMcK you are correct, when it's all pure GDI, but if D2D touches it at all, it'll have both that flickering , and the scroll bars wont act properly.Not.. that he's using d2d...

Comment: I'm also using XP as a dev platform, so no chance of d2d sneaking in.

Comment: For what it's worth, a simpler way of doing this might be to use an owner-draw listbox: if you use LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE, you can have items of different height, and Windows will take care of the scroll bar logic for you - all you then have to worry about is measuring and painting - and might get to sidestep the whole issue.

Comment: @BrendanMcK I was under the impression that the various list items must be the same height in a list box.

Comment: @eeyore - that is the case with regular listboxes, and with owner-draw that use the LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style - but the ...VARIABLE version allows for items to have variable height - you get a WM_MEASUREITEM for each item (whereas with ...FIXED, you just get one WM_MEASUREITEM that's assumed to apply to all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try sending an extra WM_NCPAINT message to the column in your WM_SIZE handler. But I thought that happens automatically.

But I find the solution proposed by BrendanMcK to make use of a default listbox the winner. Pity it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your scroll bars on your parent class, Not your child class. This will prevent repaint messages to the child class from causing the child class to completely redraw it's self. Don't handle wm_paint messages on your parent class, only in your child class. This will allow windows to do default processing on the scroll bar. And both windows need to be CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW.

Comment: I don't see how I can implement the scrollbars on the parent class. My child control does not fill up the whole window and there are several of them in the window, so it must have its own scrollbar. Do you mean that I should be creating a control of class SCROLLBAR at the top-level and handling scrolling of the children from there? That seems like asking for trouble. My child control should be self-sufficient. I'm also not handling WM_PAINT on the parent.

Comment: No, host your actual drawing window within another window, and subclass it to the parent window that's hosting the control, But considering your not using Direct 2D , this *may* be unnecessary.

Comment: whats the style your using on registerwindowclass, and createwindowex ?

Comment: I added a lot more info to my original post.